# Retrieving a JPA entity using @ModelAttribute while keeping all properties intact

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

So I have a JPA entity `Expense` which has a few properties like an id, a version, a User entity that's mapped as `@ManyToOne`.

When the user goes to the details page, the controller sends him there, adding the relevant expense object to the model in the following way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String details(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model){
        Expense expense;
        try {
            expense = expenseService.findExpenseById(id);
            logger.info("sending to details page, id is " + expense.getId());
        } catch (ExpenseException e) {
            //TODO: optionally add info message
            model.addAttribute("error", messageSource.getMessage("error_already_removed", null, sessionLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(httpServletRequest)));
            return "redirect:/expense/overview";
        }
        model.addAttribute("expense", expense);
        return "details";
    }
```

The expense object is obviously still intact here since I just retrieved it from the database, all its properties are filled in correctly.

However when the user edits the property in the view and saves this, he bumps on the following controller method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String edit(@ModelAttribute("expense") @Valid Expense expense, BindingResult bindingResult){...}
```

After a few logs however I found out the expense object only contains the properties that were present in the form on the details page (which obviously not includes the id and version). So when the program continues to merge the expense, hibernate inserts a new expense in the database since the id is null.

Things I've tried:

- Adding the id in the uri, using this id retrieving the old expense and copying the non-editable properties over the the updated expense object.
- Adding the non-editable properties as hidden input fields in the form (this gave me conversion errors however, as Spring couldn't converse the String representation of a User entity to the User entity object itself)

However both methods don't seem to feel right to me, which lead me to believe there must be a more convenient, recommended method to pass jpa entities to the model and retrieve them with their properties intact in a later method.

Comment: Have you found a satisfying solution? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @luke657 This is so long ago that I don't remember how I solved this I'm afraid :(